# Verifying three vectors are not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

Verify that for all 3-dimensional vectors $u$ and $v$, the following vectors are **not** linearly independent (using properties of cross products):

$u \times v$, $(u \times v) \times v$, $((u \times v) \times v) \times v$

**My attempted solution (which I think is incorrect):**

To prove the vectors are not linearly independent, I must show the following has non-zero solutions for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$:

$c_1(u \times v) + c_2(u \times v) \times v + c_3((u \times v) \times v) \times v = 0$

I decided to use the distributive property of cross products to factorise the above equation (which I believe is invalid since I violate the "no associativity" law of cross products):

$(u \times v) [c_1 + c_2 v + c_3v \times v] = 0$

Since $v \times v = 0$, I can then simplify the above to the following:

$(u \times v) [c_1 + c_2 v] = 0$

Therefore, I can conclude that $c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to our inital equation.

Since $c_3$ does not need to be $0$ to satisfy our iniital equation, I have therefore shown that the vectors are not linearly independent.

Given I'm aware of the problem with my solution (by factoring in the way I have done it, I believe I violate the no-associativity property of cross products), what is the correct way of solving this question?

Comment: Hint: you can assume that $u$ is orthogonal to $v$ (do you see why?). In this case, you can write the last two vectors' directions in terms of $u$, $v$, and $u\times v$.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm not sure I see why I can assume $u$ is orthogonal to $v$. I know that $u$ and $v$ is orthogonal to $u \times v$ and I know that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal to each other when their dot products are zero but I'm not sure how either of those facts can be used in this instance in order for me to assume $u$ is orthogonal to $v$ :(

Comment: What happens if you subtract from $u$ the projection of $u$ onto $v$?

Comment: Hmm, $u - proj_v(u)$ gives me a new vector $w$, that is orthogonal to $v$ and $proj_v(u)$.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm still finding it really hard to make the connection that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal. I still feel like I'm missing a link to make the connection...